# org.osmdroid.views.MapView failed to instantiate

Tags: android, android-layout, osmdroid

i really need your wonderful help.
The OSMDROID map doesn't load, i keep looking the code line by line and dont get it...............
**this code works on the phone ( shows the map perfectly )**........
*this code works on the emulator ( doesnt show the map)**

i put the screencapture
http://i1196.photobucket.com/albums/aa402/funkee_iads/osmdroidnotLoad.png

this below appears in the graphical layout

> The following classes could not be instantiated:
>   - org.osmdroid.views.MapView (Open Class, Show Error Log) See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details. Tip: Use
>   View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code when shown in
>   Eclipse

and the errorlog shows

> org.osmdroid.views.MapView failed to instantiate
>   it really weird.

i use this libs

-slf4j-android-1.5.8.jar /
-osmdroid-android-3.0.8.jar / 
-osmbonuspack_v2.4.jar /
-mapsforge-map-writer-0.3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar

here i put the code::::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="#ffd7bd"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp" >

      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffd7bd"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_marginLeft="-200dp "

        android:textStyle="bold"
   android:textColor="#000000" android:shadowColor="#8a6603"
   android:shadowDx="3" android:shadowDy="2" android:shadowRadius="1.8"
        android:src="@drawable/muestra2" />

    </TableRow>

  <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
        android:id="@+id/openmapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never expected taht but only adding a permission works perfect

> uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

no idea why i need this permission but it works

Answer (score 0):

It is among the [permissions that osmdroid requires](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/wiki/HowToUseJar). I think it is needed because osmdroid needs access somewhere to download the tiles of the map.